# Inject variable into callback function scope

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

Is this possible to add variable to callback scope? What I want to achieve is:

```
...
Foo.prototype.bar = function(fn) {
    var baz = "baz!";
    fn.call(this);
}
...
```

```
Foo.bar(function() {
    console.log(baz) // gives "baz!"
});
```

I know I can pass `baz` variable as an argument or `this` but I'm interested in something like above.

Comment: You probably mean `(new Foo).bar`, since it's a property of instances, not of the constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The only ways are the ones you pointed out: as an argument or in `this`.

Comment: Event if variable was a function? To be more precise: callback function should have access to some function defined in place of calling the callback.

Comment: @jesper: Even if the variable was a function, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

What about doing it this way:

```
var Foo = function(){}
Foo.prototype.handle = function(fn) {
    var baz = "baz !";
    eval('(' + fn.toString() + ')();');
}

var foo = new Foo;
foo.handle(function (){
    console.log(baz);
});
```