# Callback/scope understanding

Tags: javascript

So i was playing around with the concept of callbacks and i ran into a situation where I wanted to make sure i knew what i thought was happening, was actually happening.

```
function greet(callback) { // 'greet' function takes a callback
  var greeting = "hi";     // 'greeting' variable is set in the scope
  callback()               // 'callback' function is invoked 
}

greet(
function() {
  console.log(greeting)
}); 

//Console logs nothing
```

Sorta weird, you'd expect the callback() to look in its next closest scope and figure out what greeting is. However, once i declare the greeting variable to the global execution context, greeting is logged in the console.

```
var greeting = 'hi'        // 'greeting' variable is set in global context

function greet(callback) { // 'greet' function takes a callback    
  callback()               // 'callback' function is invoked 
}

greet(
function() {
  console.log(greeting)
}); 

//Console logs: 'hi'
```

Is this because technically the callback() function that's logging the variable is actually defined in the global context and is simply being invoked inside of greet()? So it's not going to look inside of greet() first, like a normal function expression would, but right into the global context because that's where it's defined.

I just wanted to make sure i understand what's happening here and not some weird scope/block issue that i don't realize.

Comment: *"you'd expect the callback() to look in its next closest scope and figure out what greeting is."* JavaScript has *lexical* scope, not *dynamic* scope. Most languages have lexical scope. The callback is not defined in the scope of `greet` and therefore doesn't have access to that scope.

Comment: Related questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8626951/inject-variable-into-callback-function-scope?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - the function has access to the scope which it is defined in.

Your example is effectively this (moving your callback to its own function):

```
var greeting = 'hi';

function greet(callback) {
    callback();
}

function logGreeting() {
    console.log(greeting);
}

greet(logGreeting);
```

As you can see, `logGreeting` has access to `greeting` at this point because it is defined in the same (or higher) scope.

**However**, when we move `greeting` into the `greet` function:

```
function greet(callback) {
    var greeting = 'hi';
    callback();
}

function logGreeting() {
    console.log(greeting);
}

greet(logGreeting);
```

`greeting` is no longer in the same or higher scope to `logGreeting`, it's in a different scope entirely, so `logGreeting` cannot look upwards through the scope in order to find `greeting`.

The scope which `logGreeting` has access to is the scope in which it is defined rather than which it is called, so it doesn't evaluate the scope when it's called with `callback()` like you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 2):

That's an example of lexical scope which is how JavaScript handles scope, as opposed to dynamic scope. In a nutshell lexical scope determines the context based on where things are defined and dynamic is based on where it's called.

For your first example to work like you thought would be dynamic scope.

You can read a bit more detail here in the "Lexical scope vs. dynamic scope" section.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses ***Static Scoping***

*TLDR;* Variables are resolved according to their location in the source code.

`greeting` is only defined with the closure of the `greet` function. Only code defined within the `greet` function closure can see the `greeting` variable.

```
function greet(callback) { // 'greet' function takes a callback
  var greeting = "hi";     // 'greeting' variable is set in the scope
  callback()               // 'callback' function is invoked 
}

greet(function() {
  console.log(greeting)
});
```

Here though, `greeting` is defined in a scope accessible by the nested closures of the `greet` function and the anonymous function used in the `console.log` call.

```
var greeting = 'hi'        // 'greeting' variable is set in global context

function greet(callback) { // 'greet' function takes a callback    
  callback()               // 'callback' function is invoked 
}

greet(function() {
  console.log(greeting)
});
```

**NOTE:** *this* keyword has a different set of rules.